# GIT HELP : main branch is empty and inactive

Tags: github

i don't know how I did it but after spending a week on a project and *thinking* i was merging everything on "main", I just realized that my main branch is not only empty,  but also that I can't pull, push, nore create pull requests from the other branches into it

Main is basically empty except for a Readme file, and the other branches are just hanging there. I also can't set an other branch to default...

What ca I do ??

Comment: Maybe you're just using another branch?... Try doing a PR into main branch

Comment: I've tried, and i just get "There isn’t anything to compare."
It's like Main is on an other project, except that it isn't, and that it's my default branch.......

Comment: Did you by chance delete your .git folder or something like that?

Comment: I think not... anyway, i eventually set an other branch as default and named it "main"
It seems to work fine !
Thx for you answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually set an other branch as default on gitHub and named it "main"
Deleted the other

Works fine !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).